# Having the scrollbar handle sized in relation to the content height

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm having a bit of trouble with this logic. My setup is typical, with a content MC and a handle MC the runs along a track with specified bounds. All I want to do is have the handle height adjust based on content height but in relation to the track height?

I'm just not sure how to tackle this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if :

`contentHeight = 200` (height of the content)

`visibleAreaHeight = 100` (height of the visible area)

`scrollBarHeight = 100` (height of the Scrollbar)

then the height of the scrollbar handle is :

```
handleHeight = (visibleAreaHeight / contentHeight) * scrollBarHeight // 50
```

The height of the handle represents the visible tip of contents.

Comment: This worked. Not sure why I was having trouble thinking of that but you helped me out a lot. Thanks!